# Date/Time manipulation in Android without java.time

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I'm writing an Android app that relies heavily on checking whether a given moment in time belongs to a certain time range. Usually I would use the java.time library, however this limits my app to API 26 or higher. It is absolutely necessary that my app runs on devices using at least API 16. Everywhere I look on the online documentation and forums I find only references to java.time, how can I perform these kind of checks in a backward-compatible way?

Edit: after some more research I found the [proper way](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) to do it through gradle desugaring.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to manage dates and times in Android is adding [Joda Time Android](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time). It provides concise, flexible and easy API for replacing standard time API. Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: According to the Readme.md on GitHub, JodaTime is no longer maintained. Anyway, the Android Gradle Plugin solves the Java8 compatibility issue using desugaring (see edit in the original post).